# java.io.FileNotFoundException: (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)

Tags: java, javafx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Создаю проект в Eclipse IDE, создал class и file в одном и том же месте.
Описал как:

```
URL urlFnumZ = HelixAtlaskirov.class.getResource("FnumZ.txt");
```

Если запустить в Eclipse работает на ура, а после сборки jar когда заворачиваю в exe с помощью программы launch4j выдает ошибку:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\G\Helix-Lab.exe!\atlaskirov\helix\jfx\FnumZ.txt (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)

Так же пробовал описать как:

```
URL urlFnumZ = HelixAtlaskirov.class.getClassLoader().getResource("FnumZ.txt"); то же самое.
```

Comment: Путь ресурса должен быть указан относительно расположения файла класса. В вашем случае это так?

Comment: И загляните в jar-файл. Проверьте, что файл там есть и находится в том месте, откуда вы пытаетесь его загрузить.

Comment: Да, относительно класса, и он находится там откуда я пытаюсь его загрузить в jar файле

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил тем что поменял метод чтения файла на:

```
InputStream urlFnumZ = HelixAtlaskirov.class.getResourceAsStream("FnumZ.txt");
Scanner fsNz = new Scanner(urlFnumZ);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если фал находится сразу под resources, то нужно добавить слеш:

```
URL urlFnumZ = HelixAtlaskirov.class.getResource("/FnumZ.txt");
```

Comment: так он мне сразу внутри IDE уже кидает ошибку:

Comment: А для чего вам путь к файлу нужен? Чтобы считать его? Если да, то лучше использовать InoutStream, могу написать для jar файла корректный вариант.